# Pay with Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to make a payment gateway with Stripe and I have more questions than solutions. I explain the business model to see if someone can help me. Company "X" has a parking APP. A user "A" can find a place to park his car and a user "B" can save the place for him. If all goes well, payment needs to be made. The "problem" with the payment is that user "A" does not pay directly to user "B" (to his Stripe account, because he does not need one?), But rather that the money goes through the company's Stripe account , the company keeps a commission and then pays user "B". What I have done so far is:

1. Create a Connected account (trial mode)
2. Create a PaymentIntent in which I put the "Amount", the "ApplicationFeeAmount" and the TransferData [Destination] of the recipient's connected account. I send the "Amount" to the company's Stripe account, subtract the "ApplicationFeeAmount" and send the money to the connected account of user "B" (which is then automatically or manually sent to his bank / card account)
   The "problem" I see with this is that when using connected accounts, the money is sent directly to the bank or debit card and I cannot use it, for example, to pay with Stripe balance.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a technical question, but a general question about how to use [Connect](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). In particular, you should spend more time familiarizing yourself with the [marketplace type model](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide), where your user B would be a service provider with a connected account and user A would just be a customer.

Paying out to user B for the service provided would be expected here, but if not you need to explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to do. If you want to control user B's balance & payouts, you can [configure those to be manual](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts) (but this is more complicated for you to manage).